# I keep getting a "Failure to send request to Livy due to exception"

Tags: azure-synapse

Trying to run a synapse pipeline but I keep getting the following error.

> "errorCode": "5000",     "message": "Failed to send request to Livy
> due to exception=[Microsoft.Marlin.Common.Exception.LivyException].",
> "failureType": "UserError",     "target": "Ingest",     "details": []
> }\

Is there any place to further see the details or figure out where the error is coming from?

Comment: I wonder if you have been able to resolve this, as I am facing the same problem. Would be thankful if you share your experience.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I am not able to resolve this.